# Написать программу через while, do while или for. C++ Програмирование цикличных алгоритмов

Tags: c++, ряды

Дано действительное число х. Вычислить с точностью 10^-6 Желательно надо что бы код содержал While, do while, или for. Так как это часть задания. Код на С++

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 double func (double x) {
    double eps = 1e-6, k = 1, memb = sqrt(fabs(x)), sum = 0;
    while (memb >= k * k * k * eps)
      sum += 1 / k / k / (k++);
    return memb * sum;
   }
}
```

Написал код но имеются ошибки помогите исправить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что не так?....

Comment: Не компилируется код

Comment: где то элментраная ошибка которая не дает программе начать работу.

Comment: Элементарная ошибка - это определение `func` в `main`.

Comment: Вообще-то это просто корень из абсолютного значения от *x*, умноженный на дзета-функцию Римана от 3... :)

    `int main() { double x; cin >> x; cout << sqrt(abs(x))*1.202056903159594285399738; }`

Кстати, ряд сходится *так себе*, так что обрезки по члену, меньшему точности, тут будет явно  недостаточно...

Comment: Посмотрите сами — https://ideone.com/99NVGM — на точность заданную и на точность реально полученную...

Answer (score 2):

Вынесите функцию из main

K должно быть целым для k++, Компилятор, наверное, об этом говорил.

После изменения потребуется обеспечить вещественное деление, достаточно 1.0 использовать

Кроме того , придется ввести икс, функцию вызвать, и результат ее нужно будет вывести

Comment: Нет, ошибка не в `k++`, а в определении функции **внутри** main. Ну, еще `#include <math.h>` надо добавить. И еще, я бы поостерегся делать `k++` внутри выражения. Вынес бы после

Comment: Ну да, я на саму функцию смотрел.

Comment: @Hisae Помогло?